# DOJO: Overriding a method in Dijit widget

Tags: javascript, dojo, overriding

I need to pass some arguments to the widget **watch** method So that it can be used in **CallBack Function**

Current Code:

```
require(["dijit/form/NumberTextBox"], function (NumberTextBox) {
    var txt = new NumberTextBox({}, "text10");
    txt.watch("value", function (name, oldValue, value) {

    });
});
```

Desired code:

```
require(["dijit/form/NumberTextBox"], function (NumberTextBox) {
    var txt = new NumberTextBox({}, "text10");
    txt.watch("value", function (name, oldValue, value, PanelID) {
        alert(PanelID);
    },PanelID);
});
```

Need to induct PanelID in watch function. I have searched the docs but it seems that we cannot pass arguments to Watch function. **Is there any way to override the Watch method and make it accept arguments?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the callback function in a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/332406) so that it keeps a local reference to the `PanelID` variable. This assumes that `PanelID` is something that is not meant to change across invocations of the `watch` function.

```
require(["dijit/form/NumberTextBox"], function (NumberTextBox) {
    var txt = new NumberTextBox({}, "text10");
    var PanelID = ... // comes from somewhere

    (function (panelId) {
        txt.watch("value", function (name, oldValue, value) {
            alert(panelId);
        });
    })(PanelID);
});
```

The callback function to the `watch` function creates a closure, so you can simplify the above code to just:

```
require(["dijit/form/NumberTextBox"], function (NumberTextBox) {
    var txt = new NumberTextBox({}, "text10");
    var PanelID = ... // comes from somewhere

    txt.watch("value", function (name, oldValue, value) {
        alert(PanelID);
    });
});
```

Comment: Learned a new thing in Javascript "closure". Thanks